# How to Insert Into a temptable from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following two procedure

1) PROC_A gives two Tables when executed eg Table1 and Table2

2)In PROC_B I need to insert the content of Table1 as returned by executing PROC_A  into a temptable inside PROC_B the columns of TABLE1 may change

I am trying Something Like this in PROC_B

```
 INSERT INTO #tem1 FROM EXEC PROC_A
```

How can I do that its not working

Answer (score 0):

if your temp table is already defined,then you do

```
INSERT INTO #tem1 
EXEC PROC_A
```

if not then,

```
sELECT * INTO #tem1 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'server=(local);trusted_connection=yes', 
'your query')
```

you also need to enable ADhoc distributed queries for open query to work..

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure 
go
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure
```

You also can use describe result set DMV in 2012,to see datatypes returned for the  query.The idea is to insert output of describe result set into temp table and dynamically build one..Further note if your SP results two result sets,only one will be returned..

```
sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'SELECT object_id, name, type_desc FROM sys.indexes'
```

Comment: temp table is not defined Is there any other way I dont know wether I will be permitted to use sp_configure in this project

Comment: Open row set is the only way to build a dynamic temp table

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Col1 SMALLINT,
    Col2 SMALLINT,
    Col3 SMALLINT,
    Col4 SMALLINT,
    Col5 SMALLINT,
    .
    .
    .
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC PROC_A

SELECT * FROM #tmp

Drop table #tmp
```

This is worked for you...